# AWS Athena PyAthena AccessDeniedException

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, pyathena

I am new to AWS.
I have a user account and two roles, one for prod one for test.

Usually I log into my account and switch to prod role to run some simple select queries.

Now I want to use Athena locally in Python with PyAthena.
I have tried the following resources from PyAthena documentation:

```
from pyathena import connect
import pandas as pd

conn = connect(aws_access_key_id='YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
               aws_secret_access_key='YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
               s3_staging_dir='s3://YOUR_S3_BUCKET/path/to/',
               region_name='us-west-2')
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM many_rows", conn)
print(df.head())
```

But always having the error

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:user/xxxx@xxxxx is not authorized to perform: athena:StartQueryExecution on resource: arn:aws:athena:ap-southeast-2:xxxxx:workgroup/primary
```

This is the exact error I would get if I run the same query using my user account without switching the role.

I have also tried to add a `profile name parameter in connect` but still not working even though the env is correctly recognised.

Could someone help me how to do the 'switch' role step in local python code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like the issue is due to a missing role and not the `profile_name` parameter. If you look at the `Connection` class in pyathena, there's a `role_arn` variable that you can specify while initializing the connection. [Here's the line I'm talking about.](https://github.com/laughingman7743/PyAthena/blob/d1bd8fe33c277cf96f33c08abe6f08c9c85aa2c8/pyathena/connection.py#L40)

You might want to try it this way -

```
conn = connect(aws_access_key_id='YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
               aws_secret_access_key='YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
               s3_staging_dir='s3://YOUR_S3_BUCKET/path/to/',
               region_name='us-west-2',
               role_arn='<your arn here'>)
```

I haven't tested it myself though since I do not have an Athena setup.

Comment: Thank you @boltthrower , it works great. I actually tried adding this parameter before but not working. So after reading your answer, I re check my role_arn and filled with a correct one and it finally worked. very appreciated!